# How do I get image coordinates on mouseover with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an image and want to use three.js to make it so that when i mouse over the image, it gives me the coordinates the mouse is over (ie: top left corner of the image is 0,0)

If possible, I would also like to take it a step further to be able to rotate that image, and be able to get the same coordinates when mousing over the image.

How do I accomplish this? Im having trouble with this.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the image in 2D or 3D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to solve this natively with canvas, but it involves Math. Canvas only display pixels so you need to hold track of the images. I found tremendous help reading the source code from this site [Canvas-pictures](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/canvasphoto/) . Therefore the props should go to Addy Osmani